# Group by version number in VARCHAR field?

Tags: mysql, group-by, grouping

On my website, I have an administrator page containing **download statistics**. I want to know, which files are downloaded most. However, everytime I release a new version (e.g. 1.3.0 -> 1.3.1) I get a new record on the table you can see below.

**Is there a way to group all versions of one item together using MySQL?**

The Version is represented in different ways:

- It's either `1.0`, `1.00` or `1.0.0`
- There's `.zip` or `.exe` behind it or  `SomeWord.zip` (e.g. "Source" or "Binaries")

The database table contains a `VARCHAR` field with the entire path of the download. For example

```
[Path] is "downloads/coding/electronics/Floppy Drive Music 3.1.zip"
```

---

## Update

Comment #1 suggests storing the versionless name in the database. I hereby also accept any answers which explain how to properly remove versions from the file name using PHP.

---

For further understanding and disclosure, please take a look at the screenshot:

[image: downloads]

Comment: You should really store the item name separate from its version. It's the only reliable way of getting this right. For instance, how else could the machine know that Floppy Drive 1 and Floppy Drive 2 are two different items?

Comment: Might be. I'm usually storing raw data while processing it in the front end. Unless someone answers, I don't have a choise, I think.

Comment: @Strawberry I updated the question. Can you suggest how do strip the version using PHP?

Comment: @bytecode77 you can use regex to split.

Comment: @TuanAnhTran Of course. But I'm not that experienced with regex. Can you help me out?

Comment: I just did it real quick; this will spit out the version number `$result = preg_replace("/(\\w*)\\ (\\d\\.\\d(\\.\\d)?)\\.(zip|tar)/u", "$2", $searchText);`

Comment: Well, in the example provided above, it's easy, because you always want everything up to the first period/full-stop. So SUBSTRING_INDEX() can help with that. But the example above may not be properly representative of the problem as a whole.

Comment: I will strip the version using PHP. I also found a regex that matches versions. See my answer below and thanks for all the comments!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not likely being done using MySQL or in a pretty way at all, I followed the advice of comment #1 of the question:

I strip the version using PHP and group by the simplyfied string using MySQL.

```
$simpleFileName = substr($row['Path'], strrpos($row['Path'], '/') + 1); // Strip path, get file name only
if (preg_match('/\d+(?:\.\d+)+/', $simpleFileName, $matches))
{
    // Replace version with "[VERSION]", which is processed in the front end.
    $simpleFileName = str_replace($matches[0], '[VERSION]', $simpleFileName);
}
```